# MySQL query SELECT as item

Tags: mysql

I was fiddling  with some mySQL I had written a while ago and I was wondering how to make the queries more efficient. After doing some research I came across a website that said
`SELECT (SELECT Value FROM table WHERE (variable1 == "answer" AND variable2 = "answer2")) AS variable;`
could be used, in theory, to return either NULL if nothing was found or the value if the criteria were met.

Having tried this, I could not get it to work. Could someone tell me if either:
1. I'm doing this stupidly and there is a more efficient system for doing this (that is not count)
2. It works, but what I'm doing wrong with it

Comment: the question is mostly what do you want to get with what data?

Comment: This will not work, if the inner select returns more than 1 row.

Comment: You could add a 'LIMIT 1' to the inner select to get round this though...

Comment: I don't think `==` is a valid operator in MySQL.  Also, you reference "count" in your question, but I don't see that in the question.  It would help if you explained what you want to accomplish; how does this not work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a a single value if it exists, otherwise NULL (instead of an empty result set), this approach is as efficient as it will get. The time it takes will be the same as the time it takes to run the inner query alone.

The only problem is that the if inner query returns more than one row you will get an error. You can fix that by adding `LIMIT 1` or making sure it never returns more than one row.